# magento website building help required

Tags: magento, webstore

I am a j2ee developer, i want to develop a webstore i choosed magento as i found its review best among open source eCommerce projects.

I have search all around the magento wiki they explaining how to configure catalogue and other options.

[Mangeto wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/welcome_to_the_magento_user_s_guide#magento_users_guide)

But i am unable to found how to list down the products on the page. is there any scripting language for it ? please help me out.

Comment: More detail would be helpful here. What page do you want to list products on? Which products? What details do you want to list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This links might help you

Managing your store
http://www.magentocommerce.com/media/screencasts

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/categories/category/manage-your-store/

Working on Theme http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide

For understanding and extending magento code http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/categories/category/development/